# Is there any way to change client_id and client_secret on the fly in IdentityServer4

Tags: c#, identityserver4

We created a multi-tenant SaaS application and I need to change client_id dynamically. How can i change client_id and client_secret in OnRedirectToIdentityProvider event ?

Comment: Why would you need to change the client_id?

Comment: another question is what needs to be changed: when client_ settings on the client side, then it has nothing to do with identityserver, when Clients on identityserver side, then it has nothing with `OnRedirectToIdentityProvider` event

Comment: then *multi-tenant* usually means just introducing the *tenant* property/claim and concern it when fetching or handling the data, but changing the name of an application depending on the tenant it's currently working with -- that's a totally wrong approach

Comment: @d_f yes u right. we need to change our way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment for @d_f it's a wrong approach. 
The right approach to do that is passing the tenant id from client to IdentityServer using the event : OnRedirectToIdentityProvider
Example

```
    options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = (loginRedirectContext) =>
                {
                    var servicesProvider = loginRedirectContext.HttpContext.RequestServices;
                    var tenantInfo = servicesProvider.GetRequiredService<IRequestContextTenantInfo>();

loginRedirectContext.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("tenantId", tenantInfo.Id);


                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                };
```

In The Identity Server You can read it in Login Action method like this :

```
var _interaction = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IIdentityServerInteractionService>();
                var returnUrl = context.Request.Query["ReturnUrl"].ToString();

                var authContext = await _interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl);
                tenantId = authContext.Parameters["tenantid"];
```

Now based on tenant id you have to know which tenant you have to connect with to verify the login process.

It's also a good practice to inject a specific custom middleware in IdentityServer4 to handle the multitenancy in the early stage in the request pipeline 
Example in Configure method in Startup :

```
 app.UseMultiTenancy();
 app.UseIdentityServer();
```

and UseMultiTenancy() method will read the tenant parameter that is sent from client.

Comment: you suggest to (partially) reimplement what's already done. when a client passes `n.ProtocolMessage.AcrValues = "tenant:some-tenant";` with auth request, IdSrv extracts it for easy access, just `context.Tenant;` see [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48384484/multitentant-identity-server-4) for the reference